# Tensorflow : result of training data(using sigmoid) came out reversely

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, sigmoid

I tried to train my data using 'Gradient Descent Algorithm' to minimize cost value,

and strangely enough, result came out differently depending on the number of steps.

Below is my training code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name="Y")
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name="bias")

hypo = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W) +b)

cost = -tf.reduce_mean(Y*(tf.log*(hypo)) + (1-Y)*(tf.log(1-hypo)))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)

#### Saving model
SAVER_DIR = "model"
saver = tf.train.Saver()
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(SAVER_DIR, "model")
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(SAVER_DIR)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for step in range(4201):
    cost_val, hy_val, _ = sess.run([cost, hypo, train], feed_dict={X:x_data, Y=y_data})

saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=step)
```

And restore model:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model/model-4200.meta')
saver.restore(sess,'./model/model-4200')

result = sess.run(hypo, feed_dict={X: x_data_test})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(Julian_test,y_data_test,'ro-') # Correct answer. all items are one of the two:0 or 1.
ax.plot(Julian_test,result,'bo-')      # Result of training. Predict answer within
plt.show() #                            sigmoid function, so all items are in range of 0 ~ 1.
```

[image: plot where step = 4200]

As figure is showing, the result of sigmoid is reverse.

But, when I changed the number of steps to **5000**, (in my above code, I only changed step.)

result came out correctly.

[image: plot where step = 5000]

I can't understand why it makes defference. Did I miss something? Need help indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in simple terms by increasing the steps you are allowing your tensorflow code/model to see the data multiple times, hence giving it the capabilities to learn more insights about the data. and generalize its representation.

E.G 
Lets say you give your model 2000 steps and at the end of 2000 steps it finds a minimum and your model stops there. but what if the minimum cost that the model has find till now is not the global minimum, we cant say cause we restricted it to 2000 steps. so lets say you increase the steps to 20000 and model now finds another minimum which gives more accurate results.

But you need to make sure that your model does-not overfit i.e giving accuracy on your training data but not on your validation set. (So make sure not to increase num steps by too much).

Comment: Thanks for comments gusain :)  I forgot to mention that every time at the end of training, I plotted step-cost graph and checked whether it is global minimum. So I think it is caused by another reason. Now i carefully guess that it just depends on luck.. of starting point. If training starts with low cost value, it could be normally ends.. Im really not sure though :(

Comment: yea it depends on that but thats not luck you can surely initialize your `weights` the way you want there are a lot of tech to do so. Also what did you mean by step cost graph and how did you check your global minimum ? i am unable to get this point?

also if you found this answer usefull would you please upvote :) thanks

Comment: I mean, At the end of training I plotted steps for x axis, cost value for y axis and checked where have occurred local minimum. So you mean control the initial weight value not randomly, but to specific constant which leads to proper initial cost?

Comment: yea you see the minimum you get at the end of the step `might` look as the global minimum of the model for the given number of ssteps, but what if model can train itself more and find more optimum solution given some more steps ? it can find a new minimum value which is better and optimum than previous, given if the steps are increased.Initialization techniques only help in getting that `global minimum` point faster.

Comment: Oh, okay I understood! The graph is plotted like one big, gradually decreasing curve though.. Honestly, I can't trust 100% about this graph my self. It's such a tough field to study :(  Thanks for your point of view, Gusain. I will try to find another way of training!